# A question about solving a Sturm–Liouville Problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am to solve the following SL problem:
$$X''+\lambda X=0$$
Given
$$X'(a)=X'(b)=0$$
The general soultion is obviously 
$$X(x)=A\cos(\sqrt\lambda x)+B\sin(\sqrt\lambda x)$$
But I cannot manage to solve these system of equations other than finding the eigenvalues
$\lambda=(\pi n/(b-a))^2$ which I have obtained by adding the two equations.
Also, tried to define an auxiliary function $Y(x)=X(a+x)$ but to no avail.

Comment: Note that you can also write the general solution as, for example, $X(x) = C \cos (\sqrt{\lambda} x + \phi)$, where $\phi$ is a real constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  note that you also have a solution for an eigenvalue of 0 in this case,  which is the constant solution X(x)=A.

Now, for positive eigenvalues,  take the derivative, and you get 
$X'(x)=-A\sqrt \lambda cos(\sqrt \lambda x)+B\sqrt \lambda sin(\sqrt \lambda x)$
From here, to solve for A and B, you put in your initial values.   Typically one of the values is 0 so you get one of $A,B$ is 0, and that'll lead the other one to be of some form of $n\pi$ or $(2n+1)\pi /2$ usually.

Now, if we don't have 0 bounds, I'm experimenting here....but still plugging in $X'(x)=0$ and moving the -A term to the other side, we get $A\sqrt \lambda cos(\sqrt \lambda  a)=B\sqrt \lambda sin(\sqrt \lambda a)$,  and the exact same equation with $b$.Dividing through, this simplifies to $\frac A B=tan(\sqrt \lambda a)$,  and the same for $b$.  So,we need to find a $\lambda$  so that $tan(\sqrt \lambda a)=tan(\sqrt \lambda b)=\frac A B$.

Going from there, I'm not quite sure

Comment: Boundaries are [a,b], which doesn't yield 0.

Comment: Yes, I made it to the same stage!